# I have two models and i want to access first and last 'rate' of Floorsheet models from Company models. How can i do it in django models?

Tags: python, django-models

```
class Company(models.Model):
    stock_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    stock_symbol = models.CharField(max_length=20)


class Floorsheet(models.Model):
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    stock_symbol = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='company')
```

As there are many transactions of specific company and I want to access first and last 'rate' from Company models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Floorsheet.objects.all().first()` and `Floorsheet.objects.all().last()`
to return the first and last object.

View the documentation for first() and last() here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#last

EDIT:

I realized that you are asking for rates from the Company model. So it'll be:

```
Floorsheet.objects.filter(stock_symbol__stock_name = <the company stock_name>).order_by('-rate').first()
```

First, you're filtering the Floorsheet model by only the matching company. The filter returns a queryset. The double underscore is a model join for foreign keys. Then you're sort the queryset in descending order by rate. Then return the first and last.